# Is there any possibilities to access the host name which is added in other system host file?

Tags: hosts, hosts-file, hostname, iis-7

I have added the new host name(www.example.com) and IP in host file at my system.I can access the website. Question is, Can access the same host name(www.example.com) in other system? Is there any possibilities?

Comment: Short answer: no

Comment: @DavidPostill thanks. I have to do from IIS bindings. Am I correct?

Comment: IIS bindings can let you assign multiple node names to the same (your) IP number but that's local. Such mapping still has to exist on a DC / DNS in order for any other net node to know about it.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to run your own Domain Controller and/or DNS node on your local net for that. In theory you could set up a DNS proxy and mess with it to serve an imposter name but that's way too much work.

If you have a bigger net system with Domain Controller and Active Directory and that box (www.example.com) is your then you can normally join it to that domain and it will propagate to DNS.

If it's a special kind of box (like Xbox Dev console, Arduino, Pi embedded system) then it's best to just keep using the IP number as name. Although I did know a guy who added his Pi to corp DC :-) and it worked fine till they switched to Azure.

Depending on what you are doing you can also bring up your own, local DC (dcpromo on server SKU-s) but if you are inside a reasonably formal net, higher DC-s won't take it as trusted.

If you area in a cowboy net (like a bigger Dev team) where everyone is admin on a higher DC then you can go and add your local DC as trusted and then you can play with zillion names. That's why I said - depending on what you are doing.